# How do I assemble a spaceship?

Tags: rimworld

The ability to build spaceships has been added to Rimworld.

I have researched everything available to me and from what I can see I have five different components I can use to build a ship:

[image]

When I assemble these in an arrangement that's allowed I end up with a branch like structure with all these misshapen parts hanging off a the ship structural beams.

How do I assemble a spaceship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build all of things in the ship tab, but make sure that they are all directly adjacent to each other. Also, the cryptosleep chamber has to be connected to the structural beam. Once built, select some colonists and make them go into the cryptosleep chambers, then press on the ship computer core and press launch. The game will warn you if you're missing a component.